# How to put multiple Data-providers to CGridView?

Tags: yii

I have two Data-providers it is like this.

```
         $marks=new Assignmentmarks;
         $student=new student;
        $criteria_st=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria_marks=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria_st->compare('st_id', $student->st_id);
        $criteria_st->addInCondition('st_id', $studentid);
        $criteria_st->compare('st_name', $student->st_name);


        $criteria_marks->compare('marks_cr1', $marks->marks_cr1,TRUE);
        $criteria_marks->compare('marks_cr2', $marks->marks_cr2,TRUE);  
        $criteria_marks->compare('marks_cr3', $marks->marks_cr3,TRUE);
        $criteria_marks->compare('marks_cr4', $marks->marks_cr4,TRUE); 
        $criteria_marks->compare('marks_cr5', $marks->marks_cr5,TRUE);

        $DataProvider1= new  CActiveDataProvider($student, array('criteria_st'=>$criteria_st,));
        $DataProvider2= new  CActiveDataProvider($marks, array('criteria_marks'=>$criteria_marks,));
```

I need to put this two Data-providers to CGridView.

Can any one tell me how to do this or if there is other way to do that I like know that as well?

Comment: u can display data from two tables using the relation in single gridview is marks table related to student table ??

Comment: make a relation beetween models. Form 1 dataprovider with join. In cgridview call relation as `$data->relation->attribute`. If you dont have relation beetween this tables watch at arraydataprovider or sqldataprovider. Form them with sql queries and pass to gridview. But this will cause problems with sorting, filtering and etc.

Comment: check this link will help you   http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30112-using-cgridview-with-2-data-providers/

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function actionIndex()
        {
            // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
            // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'

                $dataProviderHotel=new CActiveDataProvider('Hotel',array(
                    'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'hotel_rating > 8',
                        ),
                        'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageSize'=>20,
                        ),
                    ));

                $dataProviderItems = new CActiveDataProvider('Item',array(
                    'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'hotel_rating > 8',
                        ),
                        'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageSize'=>20,
                        ),
                    ));
    $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider1'=>$dataProviderHotel,
            'dataProvider2'=>$dataProviderItem
        ));
}


 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider1,
        'summaryText'=>'',
        'itemView'=>'_topHotels',  ));   ?>
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer.